# Can I populate multiple tables from one poco?

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco, micro-orm

I am investigating the use of an ORM to access our DataVault. Until now, PetaPoco looks most promising, but I am not bound to that one.

Most of the object we identify are embedded in a combination of a Hub and a Sat where the Hub contains the BusinessKey and the Sat the additional information. In a poco it would look like this (simplified):

```
// hub: H_Client
// sat: HS_Client
class Client 
{
     public string ClientId_BK  { get; set; }  // BusinessKey in the Hub

     public long H_Client_SeqId { get; set; }  // PK/Identity in Hub, FK in the Sat

     public string? Address     { get; set; }  // additional attr. in the Sat
     public string? Phone       { get; set; }  // additional attr. in the Sat
     /* and a lot more attributes */
}
```

So, whenever we talk about a Client, it always involves the combination of a Hub with its Sat. 
Usually an ORM interfaces one table at a time, but that is not very useful with datavaults: you always want to query or insert a Hub with the applicable Sat.

Is it possible to update or insert into multiple tables from one poco?

Comment: From my experience, Petapoco is a hell when it comes to joining tables. It's unclear to me however what exactly your queries will look like. Simply assigning or filtering on a foreign key is trivial in Petapoco. Or do you mean you want to pull the shown Address and Phone from the table Sat, while you query Client?

Comment: Normally, you'd select or insert (when it does not exist) a record into the hub table, retrieve the identity and insert a new record in the sat table with the identity as FK. For testing purposes, I would like to do this with poco's because they are way easier to interact with than with raw queries.

Comment: Any micro-ORM is not really an ORM, however with or without ORM, I'd create a properly named View (sql) in the db to hide all the joins then query that (as a table)

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to retrieve the info using a `ResultColumn`, but for insert/update, you will need to add your own logic (Insert in both tables with a Transaction, etc).

Remember that this kind of small, performant ORMs are meant to be simple.